# Open Excel 2010 file from Access 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel-2010

I have both Excel 2003 and Excel 2010 on my machine. I'm using VBA in Access 2010 to open 2010 .xlsx files in Excel, but I notice they seem to be "opening" in Excel 2003 because that little "Converting data" dialog box pops up for a moment.

Is there an easy way to be sure that Excel 2010 "opens" before the files open?

Answer (score 7):

I don't have two versions of Excel on my computer so cannot test but I would think that the following would open the default Excel version, which I assume you would have as 2010, and then open the file. The debug.print will tell you which Excel version is opened.

Alternatively, do you need 2003? Why not uninstall?

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.visible = TRUE

xlApp.Workbooks.Open "C:\FolderName\FileName.xlsx", True, False
Debug.Print xlApp.Version
set xlApp = NOTHING
```

EDIT: Sorry, I should also note that this opens a new instance of Excel on your machine, at the end of what you want to do you should use

```
xlApp.Quit
```

To close the instance so you don't have multiple instances running on your machine.

Also, if you need to see the spreadsheet for any reason

```
xlApp.Visible = True
```

Will do it for you