# Delete row operation in Microsoft Access

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

The picture is a snap shop of the query that i want to work on.
1. I want to delete any row that has blank W field together with all other row that share the same product_code field. for example, from the picture, 103346 has a blank W field, therefore any row with 103346 should be deleted (even if its field W is not blank).

2. I want to be able to export the new query to excel (If Possible).

I dont mind if this is through SQL or VBA code.

I am new to MS Access

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this using SQL is:

1. Create the query, and add the table (I've called mine ProductData);
2. Select the fields you want in the output;
3. In the criteria field for PRODUCT_CODE, type:

   Not In (SELECT product_code FROM ProductData WHERE W IS NULL)

The SQL should like this:

```
SELECT ProductData.PRODUCT_CODE, ProductData.PURE_QP1, ProductData.W
FROM ProductData
WHERE ProductData.PRODUCT_CODE NOT IN (SELECT product_code FROM ProductData WHERE W IS NULL);
```

And to export this to Excel, the VBA code would be:

```
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Query3", "J:\downloads\test.xlsx", True
```

Where Query3 is the name of the query that you have created.

Regards,

Comment: will this delete all the rows with the same product_code?

Comment: This is not a delete query - it just selects those records that meet the criteria. In the sample data you supplied, data for Product_codes 103346 and 103530 will not be shown, as they both have at least one record with no value in the W field.

Comment: Yeah , it did the trick. how can i export this to excel thorugh an action button? is it possible?

Comment: Answer updated to include exporting the query to Excel

Comment: but it alomst crashed my database, i had to revert. it is complaiming of no id index, when i added the vba for export.

Comment: It sounds like your database might have become corrupted. A compact and repair may fix this. I have tried this on the sample data provided in a table, and it worked fine. If you are running this from a query instead it may be better to use a make table query on your original query, and then use the SQL provided on this table.

Comment: It worked just fine but can the excel be opened automatically without having to go to where it is saved to open it?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157205/open-excel-2010-file-from-access-2010-vba

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM tablename AS t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tablename
  WHERE PRODUCT_CODE = t.PRODUCT_CODE AND W IS NULL
)
```

Comment: i will also try this method. i like trying out things

Comment: Don't you want to delete the rows?

Answer (score 0):

To delete all empty records in a Microsoft Access table. You can use:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM TableName WHERE FieldName='';"
```

There's more delete commands at the link [here](https://access-programs.com/ms-access-add-delete-update-using-sql-vba-code/)